# how to access key or value of a map in hql

Tags: hibernate, dictionary

Suppose I have the following class:

```
@Entity
public class CompanyImpl extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Map<Cat,Flight> flightCats;
```

Cat and Flight classes both have a "name" property. How can I:

1. select companies that in their flightCats map have the cat named "Meow"
2. select companies that in their flightCats map have the flight named "Ocean"

I think of something like

```
from CompanyImpl co where co.flightCats.cat.name='Meow'
```

but it doesn't work:(

---

**EDIT:** After some googling I found this [link](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2431045) that suggests a query with a theta-style join:

```
from CompanyImpl co left join co.flightCats cf where 
(cf in indices(co.flightCats)) and (cf.name = 'Ocean')
```

This query is wierd for me and I can't understand it. The funny part is that it **restricts the result by Flight objects' name**(values of the map), no matter whether I use indices() or elements()!!!

Can anybody explain to me what is going on??!!

Comment: When you say doesn't work? Exceptions?

Comment: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: cat of: org.hibernate.tutorial.annotations.Flight [from org.hibernate.tutorial.annotations.CompanyImpl co where co.flightCats.cat.name='Meow']

Answer (score 2):

It is something that is not very good documented in the (N)Hibernate documentation, but it is documented:

There are special HQL functions for it: `indices()` and `elements()`

Try something like this:

```
from CompanyImpl co where indices(co.flightCats).name='Meow'
```

The NHibernate HQL documentation mentions indices and elements in [chapter 14](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html).

Comment: Unfortunately I get a NullPointerException

Comment: +1 for mentioning of the indices(). I didn't notice this function before.